# Unity Crash report array is empty

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new with C# and unity and I'm trying to get unity crash report in my API but I'm always getting an empty array when I call CrashReport.reports, despite the fact that some crash reports exist in folder where unity stores crash details `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\Unity\Editor\Crashed\`.
In my service, I have:

```
public void Initialize()
    {

       var crashReports = CrashReport.reports;  // this always returns empty
       ...
    }
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\Unity\Editor\Crashed\` is only the unity editor crash log, not the ones of your application.

Also, `CrashReport` is currently only available in iOS.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/CrashReport.html

```
Note: this API currently is available only for iOS targets.
```